# Quantile Regression using Neural Networks (Custom Loss function)

Tags: fitting, neural-networks

I would like to perform a Quantile Regression within Mathematica's neural network framework.

Since there exist a couple of tutorials for this exact problem in Tensorflow, i.e. Deep Quantile Regression, I know this can be done by defining the right loss function for this particular problem, i.e.

$$\rho_\tau(u)= \max[ u\tau, u(\tau-1)].$$

Then a specific quantile $\tau$ can be found by minimizing the expected loss of $y-f(X)$ with respect to $f(X)$, where $f(X)$ is the predicted (quantile) model and $y$ is the observed value for the corresponding input $X$.

**My question then, is it possible to define a custom loss function for NetTrain[], and if so, how can this be done?**

---

An example of the data can be loaded by,

```
data = Flatten[Uncompress[Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/G2kdCu4i"]]]
```

Note that in this particular setting the observed values are 3-tuples.

---

Disclaimer, this is my first time using Mathematica's neural network framework.

Comment: Yes, you can, check the documentation for `LossFunction`. It can be a little limited however. It might be helpful if you give some example of the output data and the target data.

Comment: @CarlLange I did came across the documentation for `LossFunction` but it only used built-in layers which threw me off. I also added an example of my data.

Comment: It looks like your `QuantileLossLayer` answers your question - you could post it as an answer and close the question!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Going through the documentation of `LossFunction` it dawned on me that I needed to define a custom Layer via `NetGraph`, hence

```
QuantileLossLayer[τ_] := NetGraph[<|
   "thread" -> ThreadingLayer[(#1 - #2) &],
   "loss" -> ElementwiseLayer[(Max[# τ, # (τ - 1)]) &],
   "sum" -> SummationLayer[]|>, 
   {{NetPort["Target"], NetPort["Input"]} -> "thread" -> "loss" -> "sum"}]
```

It can then be used for the training on the example data, e.g.

```
net = NetChain[{8, Tanh, 16, Tanh, 3}];
trained = NetTrain[net, data, LossFunction -> QuantileLossLayer[.2]]
```

Comment: What is the net, `net`?

Comment: @AntonAntonov `net` is any neural network you deem fit, but I get your point and added an working example.